# Curried functions f#

Tags: f#, f#-scripting

I have a question regarding two types int -> (int -> int) and (int -> int) -> int. What is the difference between these two?

I read here somewhere that the first one could be interpreted as a function that that takes an int and returns a function  that takes and int and returns an int, which is the same as int ->int -> int. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `int -> (int -> int)` and `int -> int -> int` is negligible (you would really only care if you had to interop with another language).  These are curried functions which effectively take two integers and return an integer (for example, the built-in addition operator has a type along these lines).

However, both of these are very different from `(int -> int) -> int`, which takes a *function* from integers to integers and returns an integer.  As others have mentioned, the only simple example of such a function would apply the given function to a specific value (e.g. `fun (f:int->int) -> f 13`).

Comment: could you give an example of the second type?

Comment: @user1072706 - as I mentioned in my answer, `fun (f:int->int) -> f 13` is one such example.

Answer (score 3):

Good question, I suspect that functionally there's not much difference. I spent a while fiddling around trying to work out how to even get those two signatures. (John Palmer's `let fun1 i = fun j -> i + j` just gives `int -> int -> int` for me)

```
let add a b = a + b       // int -> int -> int
let inc a = add a         // int -> (int -> int)
```

I couldn't think of a non-contrived example for the second signature:

```
let foo fn : int -> fn 1  // (int -> int) -> int
```

*(This doesn't directly answer your question, but may give someone else something to chew on)*

Answer (score 2):

I dont really know F#, but it seems quite intuitive (many other language have the same notions).

1. Is a function taking an int, and returning a function that takes an int and returns an int
2. Is a function taking a function that takes an int and returns an int, and returning an int

The first would be kind of like curried function.

Answer (score 0):

So lets see what implementations would look like:

first

```
let func1 i = fun j -> i+j
```

this has a signature of `int -> (int -> int)`

note that `func1 2 3` shouldn't work

**EDIT:** It turns out that due to the way associativity works this is actually fine

but this is different to

```
let func2 i j= i+j
```

which has a type of `int -> int -> int`

here `func2 1 2` is fine

the other example we can create like this:

```
let func4 a = a 1
```

this will have a signature of `('t->int) -> u` picking a concrete `a` will work.  Note that `func4 1 2` will definitely not compile

Comment: `func1 2 3` *does* work. No need for a compiler, you can use http://tryfs.net or http://ideone.com/ :)

Comment: I believe there is an error. Func1 2 3 should evaluate to 5 since it is the same as (fun1 2) 3 . Also, since the -> associates to the right, there is no difference between int -> (int -> int) and  int -> int -> int

Comment: @MauricioScheffer , user1072706 - thanks for the correction - answer updated